# Python Sympy: Simple operations busy running even after a day

Tags: python, sympy, integral

### Objective

I am trying to symbolically solve an integral that has constant coefficients (`a_w`, `b_IN_w`, `c_IN_w`), which are composed of simple algebraic expressions.

### What I Tried

I have tried running the code given below for an entire day, but it was still running when I checked it after a day. I have used Sympy before and I understand it may not be able to solve some complex operations, where it throws some kind of message or error indicating the problem. However, in the case described below, the program is busy running even after a day, which seems unreasonable for this problem with simple expressions. Is it possible to get the solution for the below-given expression (for `q_IN_w`)?

I updated Sympy to its most recent version using conda before I ran this problem.

```
import sympy as sym

def deg_to_rad(theta_deg):
    from numpy import pi
    theta_rad = (pi/180)*theta_deg
    return theta_rad


r, a_w, a_o, a_g, b_IN_w, b_IN_o, b_IN_g, c_IN_2w, c_IN_2o, c_IN_2g, r_1, r_2, R, \
sigma_dia, IFT_ow, theta_IN_CA_deg, D_IN_ads_coeff, nablaP, mu_w, deltaP = \
sym.symbols('r, a_w, a_o, a_g, b_IN_w, b_IN_o, b_IN_g, c_IN_2w, c_IN_2o, c_IN_2g, r_1, r_2, R, \
sigma_dia, IFT_ow, theta_IN_CA_deg, D_IN_ads_coeff, nablaP, mu_w, deltaP')

l_IN_slip = sigma_dia/((sym.pi - deg_to_rad(theta_IN_CA_deg))**4)
W_IN_egy = IFT_ow*(1 + sym.cos(deg_to_rad(theta_IN_CA_deg)))
u_IN_s = (l_IN_slip*R*nablaP)/(2*mu_w)
u_IN_ads = (D_IN_ads_coeff/W_IN_egy)*deltaP
u_IN_s_eff = (u_IN_s - u_IN_ads)

b_IN_g = 0
b_IN_o = 2*(a_g - a_o)*(r_1**2)
b_IN_w = b_IN_o + 2*(a_o - a_w)*(r_2**2)

c_IN_2w = u_IN_s_eff - a_w*(R**2) - b_IN_w*sym.log(R)

q_IN_w = sym.integrate((a_w*(r**2) + b_IN_w*(sym.log(r)) + c_IN_2w)*(2*sym.pi*r), (r, r_2, R))
```

Comment: you didn't define `pi` in `deg_to_rad` I assume that has to be `sym.pi`

Comment: I am sorry. That `pi` is actually a numerical value defined as `from numpy import pi`, but I couldn't remember to include that in the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it finished in 30s, but it's quite the answer with the `sym.pi`

```
pi*R**4*a_w/2 - R**2*(pi**4*D_IN_ads_coeff*deltaP*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**4 - 720*pi**4*D_IN_ads_coeff*deltaP*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**3 + 194400*pi**4*D_IN_ads_coeff*deltaP*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**2 - 23328000*pi**4*D_IN_ads_coeff*deltaP*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg + 1049760000*pi**4*D_IN_ads_coeff*deltaP*mu_w + pi**4*IFT_ow*R**2*a_w*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + pi**4*IFT_ow*R**2*a_w*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**4 - 720*pi**4*IFT_ow*R**2*a_w*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 720*pi**4*IFT_ow*R**2*a_w*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**3 + 194400*pi**4*IFT_ow*R**2*a_w*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 194400*pi**4*IFT_ow*R**2*a_w*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**2 - 23328000*pi**4*IFT_ow*R**2*a_w*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 23328000*pi**4*IFT_ow*R**2*a_w*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg + 1049760000*pi**4*IFT_ow*R**2*a_w*mu_w*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 1049760000*pi**4*IFT_ow*R**2*a_w*mu_w - 524880000*IFT_ow*R*nablaP*sigma_dia*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 524880000*IFT_ow*R*nablaP*sigma_dia + 2*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 2*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*log(R) + pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4 - 1440*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 1440*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*log(R) - 720*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 720*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3 + 388800*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 388800*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*log(R) + 194400*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 194400*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2 - 46656000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 46656000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*log(R) - 23328000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 23328000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg + 2099520000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 2099520000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*log(R) + 1049760000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 1049760000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2 - 2*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 2*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*log(R) - pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4 + 1440*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 1440*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*log(R) + 720*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 720*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3 - 388800*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 388800*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*log(R) - 194400*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 194400*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2 + 46656000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 46656000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*log(R) + 23328000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 23328000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg - 2099520000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 2099520000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*log(R) - 1049760000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 1049760000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2 + 2*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 2*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*log(R) + pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4 - 1440*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 1440*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*log(R) - 720*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 720*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3 + 388800*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 388800*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*log(R) + 194400*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 194400*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2 - 46656000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 46656000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*log(R) - 23328000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 23328000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg + 2099520000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 2099520000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*log(R) + 1049760000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 1049760000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2 - 2*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 2*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*log(R) - pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4 + 1440*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 1440*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*log(R) + 720*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 720*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3 - 388800*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 388800*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*log(R) - 194400*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 194400*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2 + 46656000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 46656000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*log(R) + 23328000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 23328000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg - 2099520000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 2099520000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*log(R) - 1049760000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 1049760000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2)/(pi**3*IFT_ow*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + pi**3*IFT_ow*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**4 - 720*pi**3*IFT_ow*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 720*pi**3*IFT_ow*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**3 + 194400*pi**3*IFT_ow*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 194400*pi**3*IFT_ow*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**2 - 23328000*pi**3*IFT_ow*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 23328000*pi**3*IFT_ow*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg + 1049760000*pi**3*IFT_ow*mu_w*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 1049760000*pi**3*IFT_ow*mu_w) - pi*a_w*r_2**4/2 + r_2**2*(pi**4*D_IN_ads_coeff*deltaP*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**4 - 720*pi**4*D_IN_ads_coeff*deltaP*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**3 + 194400*pi**4*D_IN_ads_coeff*deltaP*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**2 - 23328000*pi**4*D_IN_ads_coeff*deltaP*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg + 1049760000*pi**4*D_IN_ads_coeff*deltaP*mu_w + pi**4*IFT_ow*R**2*a_w*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + pi**4*IFT_ow*R**2*a_w*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**4 - 720*pi**4*IFT_ow*R**2*a_w*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 720*pi**4*IFT_ow*R**2*a_w*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**3 + 194400*pi**4*IFT_ow*R**2*a_w*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 194400*pi**4*IFT_ow*R**2*a_w*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**2 - 23328000*pi**4*IFT_ow*R**2*a_w*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 23328000*pi**4*IFT_ow*R**2*a_w*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg + 1049760000*pi**4*IFT_ow*R**2*a_w*mu_w*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 1049760000*pi**4*IFT_ow*R**2*a_w*mu_w - 524880000*IFT_ow*R*nablaP*sigma_dia*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 524880000*IFT_ow*R*nablaP*sigma_dia + 2*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 2*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*log(R) + pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4 - 1440*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 1440*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*log(R) - 720*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 720*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3 + 388800*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 388800*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*log(R) + 194400*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 194400*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2 - 46656000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 46656000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*log(R) - 23328000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 23328000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg + 2099520000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 2099520000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*log(R) + 1049760000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 1049760000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_g*mu_w*r_1**2 - 2*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 2*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*log(R) - pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4 + 1440*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 1440*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*log(R) + 720*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 720*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3 - 388800*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 388800*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*log(R) - 194400*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 194400*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2 + 46656000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 46656000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*log(R) + 23328000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 23328000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*theta_IN_CA_deg - 2099520000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 2099520000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*log(R) - 1049760000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 1049760000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_1**2 + 2*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 2*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*log(R) + pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4 - 1440*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 1440*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*log(R) - 720*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 720*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3 + 388800*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 388800*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*log(R) + 194400*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 194400*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2 - 46656000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 46656000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*log(R) - 23328000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 23328000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg + 2099520000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 2099520000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*log(R) + 1049760000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 1049760000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_o*mu_w*r_2**2 - 2*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 2*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*log(R) - pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**4 + 1440*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 1440*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*log(R) + 720*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 720*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**3 - 388800*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 388800*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*log(R) - 194400*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 194400*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg**2 + 46656000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 46656000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*log(R) + 23328000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 23328000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*theta_IN_CA_deg - 2099520000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*log(R)*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 2099520000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*log(R) - 1049760000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 1049760000*pi**4*IFT_ow*a_w*mu_w*r_2**2)/(pi**3*IFT_ow*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**4*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + pi**3*IFT_ow*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**4 - 720*pi**3*IFT_ow*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**3*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 720*pi**3*IFT_ow*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**3 + 194400*pi**3*IFT_ow*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**2*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 194400*pi**3*IFT_ow*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg**2 - 23328000*pi**3*IFT_ow*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) - 23328000*pi**3*IFT_ow*mu_w*theta_IN_CA_deg + 1049760000*pi**3*IFT_ow*mu_w*cos(pi*theta_IN_CA_deg/180) + 1049760000*pi**3*IFT_ow*mu_w) + (2*pi*R**2*a_g*r_1**2 - 2*pi*R**2*a_o*r_1**2 + 2*pi*R**2*a_o*r_2**2 - 2*pi*R**2*a_w*r_2**2)*log(R) - (2*pi*a_g*r_1**2*r_2**2 - 2*pi*a_o*r_1**2*r_2**2 + 2*pi*a_o*r_2**4 - 2*pi*a_w*r_2**4)*log(r_2)
```

Comment: You are correct that if `sym.pi` is used inside the function `deg_to_rad` instead of the numerical value of `pi` as implemented in the code (edited after your comment), then it runs within a reasonable time. But, if the numerical value of `pi` is used as shown in the question then the code just keeps running indefinitely. Can you comment why is that happening?

Comment: No idea. I'm not a `sympy` expert. Perhaps this has something to do with simplifications when sympy knows `pi` instead of it's numerical value. Perhaps check the sympy bugtracker. If it's not listed, open a new issue with a minimal example where this happens too

Comment: My guess is that sympy does not work well with numpy value despite it (`pi`) being a float,  because scipy uses its own convention to store variables and constants.

Comment: SymPy will generally work better with symbolic values. For instance, `sympy.sin(pi)` will evaluate to `0` if `pi` is symbolic, but it will only evaluate to a value close to but not exactly equal to 0 if it is numeric (technically speaking, `numpy.pi` is not exactly π, so this is correct). There are lots of instances of this sort of thing.

Comment: @asmeurer Thanks for clarifying!